# Who are the "rockmen" and "adnei hasadeh"?

Tags: rashi, job-iyov-book-of

[Job 5:23 :](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.5.23)

> כִּ֤י עִם־אַבְנֵ֣י הַשָּׂדֶ֣ה בְרִיתֶ֑ךָ וְחַיַּ֥ת הַ֝שָּׂדֶ֗ה הׇשְׁלְמָה־לָּֽךְ׃
> For you will have a pact with the rocks in the field, And the beasts of the field will be your allies.

Rashi there:

> אבני השדה. מין אדם הן:

> וחית השדה. הוא שנקרא גרוש"ה בלע"ז וזו היא חית השדה ממש ובלשון משנה תורת כהנים נקראים אדני השדה:

Who are these men and creatures rashi speaks of?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18454/759

Comment: There is a whole arichus there - but given the previous question linked by @DoubleAA I won't go into it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Malbim it's an Orangutan or chimpanzee.

Malbim Vayikra 11:27:

ואדני השדה מובא בכלאים (פרק ח) ופירוש הרמב״ם חיות הדומים לבני אדם. ובירושלמי שם (ירושלמי כלאים) בר נש דטור והוא חי מן טבורא וכ׳. ולהרמב״ם יהיה אדם היערי (הנקרא בשם אראנג אוטאנג או המין הנקרא שימפאנזע).

Comment: Rashi says a type/species of man... Does this mean we are related to or evolved from monkeys?

Comment: See Sanhedrin 109 ואחת אומרת נעלה ונעשה מלחמה זו שאומרת נעלה ונשב שם הפיצם ה' וזו שאומרת נעלה ונעשה מלחמה נעשו קופים ורוחות ושידים ולילין
And that faction that said: Let us ascend to the top of the tower and wage war, became apes, and spirits, and demons, and female demons.

Comment: Not an evolution ,but rather the reverse

Comment: I don't see the connection between rashi and this gemara. Though quiet interesting.

Comment: Tiferes Yisrael on the mishna says explicitly: *orangutan.*

Comment: I wonder if he got it from the Malbim,,or vice versa